# Does Go have a format specifier for io.Readers?

Tags: go

What I want is something like this:

```golang
r := strings.NewReader("fee fi fo fum")
fmt.Printf("%r\n", r)
```

where the `%r` would be a format specifier that reads from an `io.Reader`. I didn't see anything like that in the fmt documentation https://pkg.go.dev/fmt, but it's possible I missed it.

Comment: An `io.Reader` may be a stream which never ends. If you know it ends & the payload is not too large, use `io.ReadAll`.

Comment: You did not miss anything while reading the documentation.  For the specific reader in the question, `fmt.Printf("%#v\n", r)` displays the contents of the reader in a way that might be useful to you (but probably not).

Answer (score 2):

An io.Reader may be a stream which never ends, as such a `fmt.Printf` rendering may never complete.

If you know there will be a discrete payload and it's not excessively large, you can load the contents to memory:

```
r := strings.NewReader("fee fi fo fum")
b, _ := io.ReadAll(r)
fmt.Printf("%q\n", b)
```

https://go.dev/play/p/DZybA_f6Ole

This will however move the reader current position to the end, so if you need to "replay" the reader in future calls, you need to use another io.Reader (e.g. `bytes.Buffer`) to hold the original content:

```
r := strings.NewReader("fee fi fo fum")

if debug {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    _, err = io.Copy(&b, r) // handle err

    log.Printf("io.Reader content: %q\n", b.String())

    r = &b // replay
}

// r io.Reader content and position preserved
```

https://go.dev/play/p/JRS34uX1R1G

Comment: In many cases I'm reasonably assured that the stream does have an end, and I'd like the option to act on that knowledge within the context of fmt.Printf and its ilk.

Comment: @ijt, you can write a type that wraps io.Reader and implements [fmt.Formatter](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Formatter) to do this, but as explained in this answer it renders the Reader useless.